# Alinhar imagens com CSS ou bootstrap

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap

tenho várias imagens que estão da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código no front end:

```
<div class="linha">
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Artesanato com cipó.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Artesanato com cipó">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Artesanato com fibra de bananeira - Associação Mulheres de Fibra_editado.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Artesanato com fibra de bananeira - Associação Mulheres de Fibra">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Castanha de cumbaru.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Castanha de cumbaru">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Oleo de copaíba_editado.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Óleo de copaíba">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Mel de abelha nativa sem ferrão com Castanha do Brasil.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Mel de abelha nativa sem ferrão com Castanha do Brasil">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/minicolar com sementes_editada.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Minicolar com Sementes">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Cesto de buriti.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Cesto de buriti">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Colar produzido com açaí.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Colar produzido com açaí">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Guaraná em formato de bastão.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Guaraná em formato de bastão">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Castanha do Brasil in Natura.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Castanha do Brasil in Natura">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Pitomba.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Pitomba">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Biscoito de babaçu.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Biscoito de babaçu">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Castanha do Brasil coberta com chocolate.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Castanha do Brasil coberta com chocolate">
        <img src="~/Areas/ModuloPublico/Content/img/Home/Farinha de babaçu aberta.jpg" style="max-height:100%;max-width:100%" alt="Farinha de babaçu aberta">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS aplicado:

```
.linha {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.coluna {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

    .coluna img {
        margin-top: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .coluna {
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .coluna {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Como faço para alinhar as imagens para que todas fiquem do mesmo tamanho ?

Comment: edite e pergunta e poste o código para ficar mais fácil de alguém te ajudar.

Comment: editado postei o css que está sendo aplicado

Comment: Do mesmo tamanho como? Tem imagens horizontais, verticais e quadradas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu maior problema mesmo é que vc esta usando `max-` no `width` e `height` na imagem, quando na verdade deveria usar somente `width` e `height`, sem o `max-` na frente. Pois usando `max-` vc limita a largura da imagem ao tamanho original do arquivo, e não ao tamanho disponível no *container*.

Ajustando isso ficou dessa forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.linha {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.coluna {
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

    .coluna img {
        margin-top: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .coluna {
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .coluna {
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="linha">
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Artesanato com cipó">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/200/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Artesanato com fibra de bananeira - Associação Mulheres de Fibra">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/200" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Castanha de cumbaru">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Óleo de copaíba">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/200/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Mel de abelha nativa sem ferrão com Castanha do Brasil">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Minicolar com Sementes">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/200" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Cesto de buriti">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/200/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Colar produzido com açaí">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/200" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Guaraná em formato de bastão">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Castanha do Brasil in Natura">
    </div>
    <div class="coluna">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Pitomba">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/200" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Biscoito de babaçu">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/200" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Castanha do Brasil coberta com chocolate">
        <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100" style=" height:auto; width:100%" alt="Farinha de babaçu aberta">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bom dia amigo, obrigado pela resposta, porem eu preciso que todas fiquem alinhadas iguais, sem ter essa "quebra" de margem entre elas, dessa forma as imagens ficam desalinhadas, e ha muita sobra de algumas imagens, preciso que todas sejam do mesmo tamanho, ou que pelo menos elas "terminem" na mesma linha, https://imgur.com/a/SEZ44fO nesse caso a penultima imagem está muito pra baixo, precisaria que ela terminasse na mesma linha das demais mesmo se tivesse que reduzir o tamanho da foto.

Comment: Nesse caso basta colocar além do `height:auto` um `max-height` de 100 px por exemplo. Então na classe ` .coluna img { }` vc inclui um `max-height: 100px;` além das outras propriedades que já tem lá, ai vc vai ter esse resultado http://prntscr.com/nrd4xe

Comment: pq só funciona com 100px? se eu coloco 200px ou 300px elas já desalinham novamente....

Comment: @StandAlone realmente só funcionou pq 100px é a altura padrão da menor imagem. Mas pro seu caso vc vai ter que fazer diferente. Primeiro vc tira o `max-height: 100px;` da classe `.coluna img { }`. Depois na tag `img` no HTML onde está `height:auto` vc coloca o mesmo valor para todas as imagem, tipo `<img src="..." style=" height:150px; width:100%" >`. Vc tem que colocar a mesma altura para todas as imagem e ai vai ficar sempre alinhado e proporcional. Testa ai qq dúvida me fala

Comment: muito obrigado, era isso mesmo que queria!

Comment: @StandAlone sem problemas 

Answer (score -2):

- Coloque Width e height nas divs.
- Coloque uma classe que vai receber as imagens como background.
- Na classe coloque os atributos de background-repeat:no-repeat e background-sixe:cover